# How to treat upper and lower case words the same?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

This is the code i have so far but i want it to treat the lower case and upper case words the same not sure how to though any ideas?(E.g. CASE, case and CAse the same).

---

```
sentence= input("Enter a sentence")
keyword= input("Input a keyword from the sentence")
words = sentence.split(' ')

for i, word in enumerate(words):`enter code here`
    if keyword == word:
        print(i+1)
```

---

Comment: `if keyword.lower() == word.lower():`

Answer (score 3):

To compare two words ignoring case, simply convert them both to, e.g., lower case: `word1.lower() == word2.lower()`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`str.upper()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.upper) or [`str.lower()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.lower) to turn a string into either all uppercase or all lowercase respectively.

Comment: On Python >= 3.3, [str.casefold()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.casefold) is most appropriate, which is specifically designed to remove case information.

Answer (score 2):

> to treat the lower case and upper case words the same

Use `str.lower()` function:

```
for i, word in enumerate(words):
    if keyword.lower() == word.lower():
        print(i+1)
```